# Output styled notice with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have javascript snippet:

```
<div id="store_stock_display"><p>Stock: <span class="store_product_stock"></span></p></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.store_product_stock').change(function() {
            if ($(this).text() == '0') {
                $('#store_stock_display').show();
                $(this).text('OUT OF STOCK');
            } else if ($(this).text() == '') {$('#store_stock_display').hide();} else {$('#store_stock_display').show();}
        });
    });
</script>
```

It make show Stock Level (ex: 10, 100...) if my product is IN OF STOCK and show OUT OF STOCK if my product is currently out of stock.

And I want notice will be styling as:

```
<font style="color:red; font-weight:bold;">OUT OF STOCK</font>
or
<div class="abc">OUT OF STOCK</div>
```

Please help me, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `addClass()`:

```
.abc {
    color:red; 
    font-weight:bold
}
```

```
 if ($(this).text() == '0') {
      $('#store_stock_display').show();
      $(this).addClass('abc').text('OUT OF STOCK')
 }
```

> W3C: The separation of HTML from CSS makes it easier to maintain sites, share style sheets across pages, and tailor pages to different environments. This is referred to as the separation of structure (or: content) from presentation.

Comment: Thank Raminson and Govind very very much!

Answer (score 0):

If your logic goes perfect you can go with :

```
$(this).css({'color': 'red', 'font-weight' : 'bold'});
```

add this line just after adding text.